# Plot function line specification

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a graph using a straight line in MATLAB; however, I can only print it using dot circles.

I tried changing "ro-" with "r-" and other different solutions but nothing worked. When using "r-" it does not print anything.

This is my code:

```
for T = temp
  figure(i)
  for xb = linspace (0,1,10)
    xt = 1-xb;
    Pb = 10^(6.89272 - (1203.531/(T+219.888)));
    Pt = 10^(6.95805 - (1346.773/(T+219.693)));
    Ptot = Pb*xb + Pt*xt;
    yb = (Pb*xb)/Ptot;
    plot(xb, Ptot, 'bo-.')
    hold on
    plot(yb, Ptot, 'ro-')
  end
  i = i + 1;
  saveas(gcf, filename, 'png')
end
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

How can I make this plot with lines?

Comment: You have to plot a vector directly, and not using `for` loop. Basically here, you plot one point at a time, hence the dots.

Comment: How to I go about plotting it directly?

Comment: I need the loop to get the xb and yb values

Comment: @marsei do you mean store the values in an array then plot it?

Answer (score 0):

To plot a line, the `plot` command must get all the points along the line in one function call. Repeated calls to `plot` will add new lines to the figure, and in this case each line is composed of a single point. In short, MATLAB doesn't know you want to connect these dots.

So how do you get all the data points in one array? Simply store them within your loop:

```
T = 70;
xb = linspace(0,1,10);
Plot = zeros(size(xb)); % preallocate output array
yb = zeros(size(xb));   % preallocate output array
for ii=1:numel(xb)
  xt = 1-xb(ii);
  Pb = 10^(6.89272 - (1203.531/(T+219.888)));
  Pt = 10^(6.95805 - (1346.773/(T+219.693)));
  Ptot(ii) = Pb*xb(ii) + Pt*xt;
  yb(ii) = (Pb*xb(ii))/Ptot(ii);
end
figure
plot(xb, Ptot, 'b-')
hold on
plot(yb, Ptot, 'r--')
```

But it is actually easier to do this without a loop at all:

```
T = 70;
xb = linspace(0,1,10);
xt = 1-xb;
Pb = 10^(6.89272 - (1203.531/(T+219.888)));
Pt = 10^(6.95805 - (1346.773/(T+219.693)));
Ptot = Pb*xb + Pt*xt;
yb = (Pb*xb)./Ptot;    % note ./ is the element-wise division
figure
plot(xb, Ptot, 'b-')
hold on
plot(yb, Ptot, 'r--')
```